# Regex to parse file where records are delimited with new line, fields with comma, but both comma new line can be in strings

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, parsing, csv

I have to parse a string in VB.NET, which has the following structure

1. records separated by new line
2. fixed number of fields per record, separated by comma
3. fields can be quoted (strings) or not quoted (other type of data - date, int, etc)
4. Comment fields (strings) can contains both new line and comma

so, due to point 4, comma and new line must be ignored as field / record separators if between a odd and even quote (e.g. if between quote 1 and 2, they are in comment field and must be ignored, but if between quotes 2 and 3, they are field / record delimiter.

I can write manual parsing code for this, but think a regex can be more reliable. But I have very limited experience with regex.

Example string

(record 1)

> 10,"Test",10.1,,,"123"

(record 2)

> 20,"Test, has comma
>   and new line",,2.1,,"aaa"

So actual string is

> 10,"Test",10.1,,,"123"
>   20,"Test, has comma
>   and new line",,2.1,,"aaa"

---

**EDIT:**
I need to add more clarifications:
1. records can have more or less then 4 fields
2. fields can be empty

So an actual test input string can be

> 10,"Test",10.1,,,"123"
>   20,"Test, has comma
>   and new line",,2.1,,"aaa"

So apparently the problem should be split in two:

1. Extract records (where new line is not between quotes)
2. for each record, extract fields (where delimited by comma not between quotes)

How should I split the regex, (or have two regexes) to match this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think a regex would be more reliable?  If it's harder to write it's probably harder to read as well, and therefore harder to maintain.

Comment: I don't think you can say generally that if something is harder to write, it's harder to maintain. In the important case where the difficulty of writing is due to lack of knowledge, once that knowledge is acquired, both the writing and maintenance can be easier than the alternative. In general, I prefer regex to traditional code where the regex is "reasonable".

Comment: Where I work the dev turnover rate is very high, and I've yet to meet a dev who really groks regex... which has always led me to avoid it.  This is also in line with the old adage:   “You have a problem so you solve it with a regular expression. Now you have two problems.”

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to eliminate the redundancy for the expression for each field, but the following appears to work for your example, per [this test](http://rubular.com/r/xmehFNut1o):

`("[^"]*"|[^",\n]+),("[^"]*"|[^",\n]+),("[^"]*"|[^",\n]+),("[^"]*"|[^",\n]+)`

If you use a repeating group, the match will only be retained for the last instance.  If anyone knows how to get around this duplication, I'd be inerested.

Update: If you know something about the type of each positional field (e.g. whether it's a quoted string, integer, float, etc.) you can of course adjust the regex accordingly.

Comment: I was just working on the same regex and came up with this: `new Regex(@"([\d\.]+),""(.*?)"",([\d\.]+),""(.*?)""", RegexOptions.Singleline)`. It avoids using character groups by using the non-greedy modifier.

Comment: I'm not familiar with vb.net, but doesn't the SingleLine qualifier preclude matching across the newline, one of the key requirements here?

Comment: `SingleLine` allows the dot to match `\n`. .Net regexes can handle multiline by default.